# Set IDs for post cDataProvider with array in Yii

Tags: yii

I have to table without relation:

favs:

- id
- user_id
- content_id

posts:

- id
- title
- content

I will find all favs that user_id = 4 and set finded favs array in CDataProvider for find all posts that's id exist in top array.

How i can do this in yii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT content_id FROM favs WHERE user_id = 4";  
$favs = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();  
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('id', $favs);  
$posts = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);
```